# Redirect to specific URL after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, redirect

I am building a system when someone requesting, the email notification is sent to their supervisor as a notification to accept the request. When the supervisor open it, then click to the button, it redirect to the login page. The problem is I don't know how to redirect to spesific approval page after login. The link in email button is link to spesific page. When it click, it check if the user already login or not. If user already login, it will smoothly ridirect to approval page. But when the user hasn't login it will redirect to login page. After the user login, how to make it redirect to the link I set in email.
 I've search in but I didn't get clear answer how to solve this. Hope anyone can help me here

```
function do(){

    $nik = $this->input->post('nik');       
    $pwd = sha1($this->input->post('pwd') . $this->config->item('encryption_key'));
    $login = $this->Login_model->auth($nik, $pwd);

    $rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'nik',
            'label' => 'NIK',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'pwd',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error message.');
            $this->load->view('v_login');
        } else {
            if ($login == NULL) {
                echo "<script>alert('Check your NIK or Password or Register new account')</script>";
                redirect('login','refresh');
            }else {
                $data = array(
                    'ID'        => $login->no,
                    'nik'       => $login->nik,
                    'name'      => $login->name,
                    'email'     => $login->email,
                    'is_login'  => TRUE
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                $session_nik = $login->nik;
                redirect('dashboard');
            }


        }  
    }
```

Thank You :)

Comment: show the code you tried and explain your errors you are facing

Comment: I have updated the question, I didn't get any error, but I don't know how to redirect to the link I set in email

Comment: Please post your code. We can't guess what the problem may be. @kitcat

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've updated it

Comment: @kitcat Ok thanks. Well seeing this is  a CI question, I'm not the guy for this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using CodeIgniter have you looked at this? https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/

You can create a form that will handle logging in the user.

Something simple like this (without any styling):

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="login_form">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="password">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Then you can setup a PHP script to get the form information and validate the request

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if($_POST['username'] == 'example' && $_POST['password'] == 'password') {
    // Let them through
    $_SESSION["admin"] = true;
    ob_start();
    header('Location: yourfile.php');
    ob_end_flush();
  } else {
    // You would set this up yourself.
    die();
  }
}
```

Then on the `yourfile.php`, we need to make sure you are an admin.

```php
if ($_SESSION["admin"] == false) {
  ob_start();
  header('Location: login.php');
  ob_end_flush();
  die();
}
```

Comment: are you using codeigniter ?? questions asked in codeigniter why are you answering to use core PHP

Comment: @BoominathanElango Woops! Didn't see it in the title or the body, I now just looked at the tags after I made my response.